# How do I change css on only part of a link_to link?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

If I have a `<%= link_to "BlueBottles" %>`, how do I change CSS on only part of it, say, to make the first four letters Blue?

Separate links just doesn't look right and I'm afraid I'm falling short on the proper way to do it. Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Rails helpers, you would have something like this (remember to replace `your_path` with the appropriate Rails route):

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:b, 'Blue') + 'Bottles', your_path %>
```

And then is your CSS, like in Bastian Rang's answer:

```
a > b {
  color: blue;
}
```

Edit: changed `:em` to `:b` as per Bastian Rang's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

if you the following link

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">BlueBottles</a>
```

You may change it to

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"><b>Blue</b>Bottles</a>
```

and style `a > b {color:blue}` in your CSS

instead of the B-Element, you can use `em`, `strong` or even `i`

Comment: Semantically it may be better to use a <b> tag rather than <em> unless it is being emphasised.

Comment: The <b> tag is never a better option semantically than <em> or <strong>, for the simple reason that it describes presentation rather than semantics.

Comment: @mdepolli not, it does not strictly describes presentation. if you refer to the html5-standard there is a specific semantic meaning for all of them - and a default representation.

Comment: stated  "Nov 7 '08 at 11:07" - before html5 was thought about. - you are right, if you stick to lower html or xhtml-versions. the current version of html is 5  - and there we have semantics in all of them: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element

Answer (score 0):

There's a block form for `link_to`, I think this is a case where you want to use it :

```
<%= link_to your_path do %>
  <span class='special_anchor_part'>Blue</span>Bottles
<% end %>
```

Then css :

```
.special_anchor_part{ color:blue; }
```

Comment: thanks for your help...they still end up getting displayed as separate links, with a gap in the middle. Is there a way to keep the link as all one word but with different stylings?

Comment: They're not supposed to display as two links ... you may have some extra css that breaks it, `display: block` on the span maybe ... try to analyze the output in Firebug/chrome inspector to see where it comes from